# Как сделать сортировку в БД по количеству объектов в ListField? Используется Mongoengine

Tags: django, mongodb, django-rest-framework

Имеется следующая модель:

```
class Departments(Document):
    _id = fields.ObjectIdField()
    name = fields.StringField(blank=True, null=True)
    department_id = fields.StringField(blank=True, null=True)  # Added
    list_of_users = fields.ListField(blank=True, null=True)
    list_of_workstations = fields.ListField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Как вы можете видеть `list_of_users` и `list_of_workstations` являются списками объектов.

Я написал на Питоне код, который вытягивает из БД все данные, помещает в словарь, и производит сортировку, но данный метод работает слишком медленно.

Как я могу отсортировать `Департаменты` прямо в БД по количеству `list_of_users` или `list_of_workstations` или по соотношению  `list_of_users/list_of_workstations`, примерно как:

```
departments = DepartmentStats.objects.order_by(len(list_of_users)).dsc
```

или

```
departments = DepartmentStats.objects.order_by(len(list_of_users)/len(list_of_workstations)).dsc
```

?

Comment: Явно не совсем то, что нужно, но можно добавить поле наподобие **number_of_users** и писать туда количество, а сортировать уже по этому полю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый быстрый вариант (с запросами прямо в БД), потому как питон данные запросы в моем случае (где данных больше, чем представлено ниже) обрабатывает до 4х минут, против пары секунд с запросами в БД:

```
departments = DepartmentStats._get_collection().aggregate([
    {"$project": {
        "department_id": 1,
        "name": 1,
        "list_of_users": 1,
    }},
    {"$sort": {"list_of_users": -1}},
])
```

И в случае, когда нужно отсортировать по соотношению `list_of_users/list_of_workstations`

```
departments = DepartmentStats._get_collection().aggregate([
    {"$project": {
        "department_id": 1,
        "name": 1,
        "list_of_users": 1,
        "len_list_of_items": {"$divide": [{"$size": "$list_of_users"},
                                          {"$size": "$list_of_workstations"}]}
    }},
    {"$sort": {"len_list_of_items": -1}},
])
```